# redis:- query for particular 'email' in value

Tags: node.js, express, redis

Using redis store in express.

```
app.use(express.session({
      store: new RedisStore({
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 6379,
        db: 0,
        pass: 'RedisPASS'
      }),
      secret: '1234567890QWERTY'
    }));
```

The above creates

```
key : 'sess:0t-8-qJG5s0e3w4oGhBjxgAH  
value: {\"cookie\":{\"originalMaxAge\":null,\"expires\":null,\"httpOnly\":true
        ,\"path\":\"/\"},\"user\":{\"__v\":1,\"_id\":\"52946af6eee73dc84600000c\"
        ,\"email\":\"sa@abc.in\",\"name\":\"sa@abc.in\"}}
```

In the above, from node interface, how do you query for particular 'email' in value?

I presume i would need to include `redis = require('redis');` in node.

Comment: Redis is a key-value database, you can't "query" the data stored in it, you can access it only by its key.

Comment: The best solution I may suggest is to create a dictionary for all user emails. You may store it in redis along with session.

Comment: @LeonidBeschastny how may i do that? since the entry is being created when session begins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As everybody else said, for this use case you probably want to use a different approach. The way to go with Redis (as in any key/value store) is denormalize your data so you keep different "indexes". If you know you need to access your sessions via email for any reason, then what you want is right after creating the session store a key  like

SET session_by_email:YOUR_USER_EMAIL SESSION_KEY

in your example

SET session_by_email:sa@abc.in 'sess:0t-8-qJG5s0e3w4oGhBjxgAH

now if you need to access the session using the email, all you need is to GET the session key by using the email, then getting the session data

In a not recommended approach, you could also traverse all the keys by using something like

KEYS 'sess*

So you would get all the keys stored with session info, and you could search (client side) the email for each. This would be time consuming and of course I recommend the reverse index option, but if for any reason you needed to use this approach, then upgrade to redis 2.8 and use the SCAN command instead, so you can query your keys in an efficient way.

Answer (score 0):

Not very sure what you are asking, but for accessing the session variable for a request, you would to access `req.session.user.email`, regardless of what session store is used.

Comment: i wanted to query, the req.session.user.email from outside the session. The above works to give the session's own email. I want to query for particular 'email' from all session values.

Comment: @SangramSingh ah. You can't query stuff like that in Redis. Remember, your session isn't for storing data in the backend. You need a proper database for that. The session is just for communicating and storing user data on the front-end.

Comment: The only reason I am using redis as store is, to manipulate req.session of another user. So i use mongodb instead, perhaps?

Comment: i believe redis is storing the session as a String, can i make it store as a hashtag, maybe that helps?

Comment: @SangramSingh yes, you can use hash or mongodb, but why would you ever want to manipulate the session of another user? Whatever you are trying to do, this is not the right approach for it.

Comment: okay, user1 does, activity based on which, user2 gets notification, by simply updating req.session.notification. Not the right approach?

Comment: @SangramSingh No. Don't store notifications in sessions. Won't go into detail, but that is not what sessions are for. You need to design a database schema for processing, storing and displaying notifications. You can use redis to just store the notifications too, but don't use it via sessions.